# Android 4+ doesnt show the the options menu in a grid layout

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, interface, menu

I've some troubles in Android 4+ with menu because it displays menu item in a list. But I can't a way to set it displaying in a grid-like layout as it used to be, i tried **@android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar** on the activity manifest but when I do that the actionbar that I'm using disappear and the application has an actionbar. Thanks

Comment: You may do better by clarifying what you tried with the theme - you say the actionbar you were using disappeared, but then the application *had* an actionbar?

Answer (score 2):

> I can't a way to set it displaying in a grid-like layout as it used to be

There is no way to revert to the old behavior while retaining an overall modern look to your app. Moreover, every other app on that user's device will "displays menu item in a list". Please allow your app to behave like all the other apps on the user's device.

Comment: "like all the other apps"  Not all apps display the ugly top title bar. And if you hide it, menu is not accesible, right? The little button with 3 dots aligned vertically (menu button) was a great thing.